# Intellisense is incorrect, after the "style" attribute, when editing an ASP.NET control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

When I'm editing an aspx file in Visual Studio, Intellisense is always wrong after i manually enter a "style" attribute.

Intellisense shows correctly when I start they "style" attribute:

[image]

However, when I *end* the style attribute, I expect Intellisense to stop displaying elements for "style", and show me normal ASP.NET control related elements.  But, it continues to display "style" elements:

[image]

Since the "style" attribute has ended, I would expect the "normal" ASP.NET Intellisense to show up, like it does before the style attribute:

[image]

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?  My workaround has always been just to write out the style attribute last, but it's pretty darn annoying.

Comment: If you press Esc to close the intellisense window, then hit Ctrl+Space to restore it, which intellisense do you get?

Comment: The correct (non-css) intellisense

Comment: The _real_ problem here is inline styles; `style` is a valid attribute on an HTML element, but is not an explicit property of server-side ASP.NET control elements - they expose the `CssClass` property to specify classes of properly separated styles. Technically _is_ a bug, though, since Intellisense tries to support it anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - I had the same suspicion, so I looked up the MSDN documentation.  Style **is** a true property of the Button class and it is inherited from WebControl.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=VS.100).aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything incredibly obvious.  It looks like this bug has existed since at least Visual Studio 2008.

I hadn't noticed this behaviour, probably because I use ReSharper which provides its own intellisense functionality.

The workarounds seem to be:

- Put the style attribute at the end so you don't have to worry about it (as you suggested)
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to reinitialise the intellisense
- Just press <kbd>Space</kbd> a couple of times after the closing quote and it eventually switches back to the correct context.

You could lodge a bug with [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) but I have had little success there myself.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it back in 2008 as well.  I just figured maybe I was thinking about it wrong, or there was some bizarre config option that was escaping me.  Thanks :)